# Message [-fpermissive] when calling functions in C++

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I am trying to run a simple C++ program. Whenever I run the code I get the same output 'error: passing 'cont Point' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]'. The problem seems to be occurring whenever I call the set function. I am still new to C++ and am still trying to get familiar with its functions so I apologize if the answer may seem obvious. Below is the code that is giving me problems:

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QString>

class Point {
  public:
    Point(int px, int py)
       : m_X(px), m_Y(py) {}

    void set(int nx, int ny) {      
        m_X = nx;
        m_Y = ny;
    }
    QString toString() const {      
       // m_X = 5;                 
        m_Count++;                  
        return QString("[%1,%2]").arg(m_X).arg(m_Y);
    }
  private:
    int m_X, m_Y;
    mutable int m_Count;            
};


int main() {
   QTextStream cout(stdout);
   const Point p(1,1);
   const Point q(2,2);
   p.set(4,4);                      
   cout << p.toString() << endl;
   q.set(4,4);                    
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `-fpermissive` is not the error message. It is just a hint how one can circumvent the error message being fatal. (But don't ever use that flag!). The error message is printed before that hint in the same line and additional information before and after the line containing it. Please add the full compiler output to the question.

Comment: Notice that `p` and `q` are `const Point` so the operations `p.set` and `q.set` are not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you cannot modify an object marked as `const`, which is a keyword used in C++, a synonym of "non-modifiable", used to tell the compiler that a variable cannot be modified. In your main,

```cpp
const Point p(1,1);
const Point q(2,2);
p.set(4,4);                      
q.set(4,4);
```

the variables `p` and `q` are of type `const Point` but the member function `Point::set` is not marked `const`. Since the member function `Point::set` is not a `const` member function of class `Point`, the compiler thinks the function tries to modify the object it is called on (in the statement `p.set(4,4);` the function `set` tries to modify `p`), but this is not allowed since you marked `p` (and `q`) to be `const`, recall, "non-modifiable".

Now, notice that you *could* mark member function `Point::set` as `const`, but that would be nonsensical since you *want* to modify the variables (in this case `p` and `q`). A solution would be to drop the `const` qualifier from `p` and `q`.

You can [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqd9ILyQRxQ) to learn about const member functions; you can also [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4etjb2_KAaE) to learn more about member functions in C++.